# How to encrypt and decrypt a String in Apex using the Crypto class

Tags: apex, crypto, encryption

Please provide apex code examples to encrypt and decrypt a string using all of the supported encryption algorithms (AES128, AES192, and AES256). I searched for clear and concise code examples on this site, but found none (if you know of an answer with all said examples, please point me that way). I have tried to encrypt a String with the Crypto class, but was unsuccessful. Instead of debugging my code, I think it will be more helpful to look at some working examples.

Thanks :D

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The below wiki gives good set of examples for crypto classes

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class

A sample scenario from above article

```
// Generate an AES key for the purpose of this sample. 
// Normally this key should be stored in a protected custom setting 
// or an encrypted field on a custom object
Blob cryptoKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);

// Generate the data to be encrypted.
 Blob data = Blob.valueOf('Test data to encrypted');
// Encrypt the data and have Salesforce.com generate the initialization vector
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoKey, data);
// Decrypt the data - the first 16 bytes contain the initialization vector
 Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoKey, encryptedData);

// Decode the decrypted data for subsequent use
 String decryptedDataString = decryptedData.toString();
```

Here is below blog that points a use case of how to store once we encrypt data in sfdc

http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.in/2014/01/encrypting-xml-response-from-external.html

Basically there are two versions

> WithManagedIv()
>
> Here SFDC itself handles vector generation
>
> Encrypt()
>
> Here one needs to include vector also as parameter for encryption.

Answer (score 14):

Finally got it working:

```
public class CryptoExample {

public static void test(){
    CryptoExample.aes128();
    CryptoExample.aes192();
    CryptoExample.aes256();
}

public static void aes128(){
    //text to encrypt
    String clearText = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';

    //16 byte string. since characters used are ascii, each char is 1 byte.
    Blob key = Blob.valueOf('1234567890123456');
    //encrypted blob
    Blob cipherText = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, Blob.valueOf(clearText));
    //encrypted string
    String encodedCipherText = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cipherText);

    System.debug(encodedCipherText);

    //encrypted blob
    Blob encodedEncryptedBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(encodedCipherText);
    //decrypted blob
    Blob decryptedBlob = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, encodedEncryptedBlob);
    //decrypted string
    String decryptedClearText = decryptedBlob.toString();

    System.debug(decryptedClearText);
}

public static void aes192(){
    String clearText = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
    //24 byte string. since characters used are ascii, each char is 1 byte.
    Blob key = Blob.valueOf('123456789012345678901234');
    Blob cipherText = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES192', key, Blob.valueOf(clearText));
    String encodedCipherText = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cipherText); 
    System.debug(encodedCipherText);
    Blob encodedEncryptedBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(encodedCipherText);
    Blob decryptedBlob = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES192', key, encodedEncryptedBlob);
    String decryptedClearText = decryptedBlob.toString();
    System.debug(decryptedClearText);
}

public static void aes256(){
    String clearText = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
    //32 byte string. since characters used are ascii, each char is 1 byte.
    Blob key = Blob.valueOf('12345678901234567890123456789012');
    Blob cipherText = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', key, Blob.valueOf(clearText));
    String encodedCipherText = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cipherText); 
    System.debug(encodedCipherText);
    Blob encodedEncryptedBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(encodedCipherText);
    Blob decryptedBlob = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', key, encodedEncryptedBlob);
    String decryptedClearText = decryptedBlob.toString();
    System.debug(decryptedClearText);
}}
```

Edit:
Thanks Chuck Mortimore for providing the code that I build these examples from.
[Sample Java class to decrypt AES128 encryption](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2288/sample-java-class-to-decrypt-aes128-encryption)