# AES 256: Apex Encryption to Java Decryption

Tags: apex, java, encryption, decrypt

Could you please help how to decrypt the data in java. It was encrypted by SFDC Apex (AES 256)

```
Blob cryptoKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);
Blob data = Blob.valueOf('Test data to encrypted');
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoKey, data);
```

Please provide some code, how to decrypt using java.

I didn't understand **Crypto.generateAesKey(256)** how do we generate key in java to decrypt?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: To decrypt in Java you will have to export the same `cryptoKey` bytes used to encrypt in Apex. Code like https://gist.github.com/bricef/2436364 shows you what the Java should look like. But be aware that the 256 key size is not one of the "required" Ciphers for a JDK (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) so you may need to obtain a 3rd party security provider. Its somewhat awkward Java code to get right so if you are lucky someone may post a complete example.

Comment: Just noticed this [Sample Java class to decrypt AES128 encryption](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2288/sample-java-class-to-decrypt-aes128-encryption).

Comment: Thanks a lot @KeithC...  **Crypto.generateAesKey(256)** is this statement does random key generation? do i need to ask Apex team to export this cryptoKey? to decrypt in java or any possibility of generating same key in java itself.

Comment: You can store the blob and extract it yourself. (Or you could present the blob as base64 text in a Visualforce page and cut and paste.) Such keys have seed values and a massive amount of randomness built in; if they didn't other people could decrypt. So you will have to use the same key bytes in Java as your do in Apex.

Comment: hi @Jagadeesh, did you find a way to get the key string from blob?