# How to decrypt AES-256 in node.js

Tags: crypto, node.js

I'm struggling to decode a piece of AES-256 encrypted base64 coded data in node.js. The data was encoded in Salesforce. I tried various different aes algorithms but without luck.

I'm crypting and encoding the data in the developer console using anonymous APEX using this code.

```
String clearText = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
Blob key = Blob.valueOf('abcabcabc1abcabcabc1abcabcabc132');
Blob cipherText = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', key, Blob.valueOf(clearText));
String encodedCipherText = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cipherText); 
System.debug(encodedCipherText);
```

In node I'm trying to decrypt with the following lines. I got the "cryptoStr" from the debug output of the anonymous apex.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
    algorithm = 'aes-256-cbc',
    password = 'abcabcabc1abcabcabc1abcabcabc132';

var cryptoStr = 'Q336OpFur65nt1NgGUebbgx5hmwpcH3iUEd4mXq8qVwXL91qpLSaFecgKpsVvQEiT0DOMwK3TpUksPnjbr3wKA==';

var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm,password);
decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
var dec = decipher.update(cryptoStr,'base64','utf-8');
dec += decipher.final('utf-8'); 

console.log('Decrypted content: ' + dec);
```

Any ideas are most welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [this great post by Chuck Mortimore](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2288/sample-java-class-to-decrypt-aes128-encryption) about a similar problem but when crypting in Salesforce and decrypting in Java. I was able to port this to node and it worked great. I hope this will be useful for someone else too.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

password = 'abcabcabc1abcabcabc1abcabcabc132';
var cryptoStr = 'Q336OpFur65nt1NgGUebbgx5hmwpcH3iUEd4mXq8qVwXL91qpLSaFecgKpsVvQEiT0DOMwK3TpUksPnjbr3wKA==';

var buf = new Buffer(cryptoStr, 'base64');
var iv = buf.toString('binary', 0, 16);
var crypt = buf.toString('base64', 16);

var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', password, iv);
decipher.setAutoPadding(false);
var dec = decipher.update(crypt,'base64','utf-8');
dec += decipher.final('utf-8'); 

console.log('Decrypted content: ' + dec);
```

Comment: In Node v6 and above the `iv` needs to be calculated slightly differently.

`var iv = buf.slice(0, 16);`

That should save a few people some wasted brain cycles. :-)